# How to add custom properties to A component

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

file name MyClass

```
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public var checked:Boolean;

            private function init():void {

                checked = false;

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Tile>
```

I've created a file with this code, do I have to create a object of this Custom class to set custom properties

in my module added this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Module 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" initialize="init();"
    xmlns:MyComp="components.*">

var t:Tile = new MyClass();
```

but I get an error that class is not found..what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a component you must also call it with that name

if I understood your example right, you must use

```
var t:MyClass = new MyClass();
```

instead of

```
var t:Tile = new MyClass();
```